# VB.NET RFID plug and play pass to variable the rfid code

Tags: vb.net

When im using a plug and play rfid reader it th rfid code directly go to textbox that has the focus.
How can i directly pass the rfid code to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Some vendor, providing SDK to handling read event for their product. do you got the SDK?

Typically RFID device just like a keyboard device, you can't take the value directly into variable (except using SDK).

Since you need to capture the value, why don't you let the textbox catch the value, and then you read the value using `change()` event from the textbox.

Comment: Hi thanks, i dont have the SDK but i will ask for that, on the part of textbox.
That was really my first option but if i do that ithe focus should always on the textbox what i want is if i scan rfid it will directly go to a specific texbox is it possible?

Comment: Enable Keypreview in your form then handle the Keydown event of your form.

Comment: You can use tricky technique, you can use a timer to force the textbox still on focus. Or create some SOP, and tell the user, to focusing the textbox before they scanning RFID card (this method only work if the device handled by an operator).

Comment: You could just skim the data directly from the serial port you are connecting over and then do whatever you'd like with it.